# Can't compile SocialBootstrapApi

Tags: servicestack

I downloaded the SocialBootstrapApi from GitHub but I can't run the example.
When I try to run it I get:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0234
The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'
(are you missing an assembly reference?) SocialBootstrapApi

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0234
The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'
(are you missing an assembly reference?) SocialBootstrapApi
```

When I look at the Global.asax.cs file it looks like it's missing s reference to System.Web.Mvc. Nuget shows it as being installed. I tried installing several versions of MVC, still won't compile.
The read me file said to add:

```
<add namespace="ServiceStack.Mvc" />
```

to the web.config file, which I did, but it still won't compile.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

-Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Web.Helpers` namespace was left over from its original MVC 3 template which used to be automatically installed by older versions of VS.NET in your GAC and can be installed using [Web Platform Installer](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3).

But SocialBootstrapApi doesn't need these namespaces so I've just [removed them in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/SocialBootstrapApi/commit/ba8535dfe401b047220ddd78391d05580d6e9a6f). You should be able to pull the latest version of SocialBootstrapApi or just delete the namespaces manually. Otherwise installing MVC 3 will also work.

Comment: Well I think that moved me in the right direction but now I get the following error: The name 'FilterConfig' does not exist in the current context. I get it on FilterConfig, RouteConfig and BundleConfig. I'm not sure what library I'm missing to make these work. I was getting an error on Microsoft.asp.net.Web.Pages but re-installing it seemed to fix that error.

Comment: OK I see the files in the App_start folder so I guess I just need to investigate why they can't be seen in Global.asax.cs

Comment: OK it looks like AppHost can't compile. It can't seem to see any of the services in SocialBootstrapApi.ServiceInterface. When I open the HelloService I don't see any obvious errors. There are 40 errors complaining about classes that don't exist. The very last error is "Could not load type 'SocialBootstrapApi.MvcApplication'"

Comment: @user2033791 you're missing ASP.NET MVC3 which you can [install with the Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MVC3) - In the meantime I'll look at upgrading it to the latest MVC5 template.

Comment: OK looks like it's all working now--just some bad code/temp files from the last project. I cleared everything out and the project builds as expected. Thanks for your help.